# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: excel, jsp

i have the below jsp.

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : See_Free_Editors
    Created on : Aug 16, 2013, 7:22:30 PM
    Author     : u0138039
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker();
            });
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            function getUsers()
            {
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=
                    function()
            {
                if(xmlHttp.readyState===4 && xmlHttp.status===200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('b').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText; 
                   }
                   else
                       {
                           document.getElementById('b').innerHTML="Waiting";
                       }
            };


            xmlHttp.open("post", "see_frm_DB.jsp", true);
            xmlHttp.send();
 }
        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.6em; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Date Request received
                        </label>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type='text' class='datepicker' name='date1' id="date1"></td>
                    <td><label>Date Request received
                        </label>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type='text' class='datepicker' name='date2' id="date2"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="submit" onclick="getUsers();"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="b">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the connection is as below.

```
 <%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Aug 19, 2013, 8:07:29 PM
    Author     : U0138039
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try{
        String a=request.getParameter("date1");
        String b=request.getParameter("date2");
        out.println(a);
        out.println(b);
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        sql="select * from [Sheet1$] where [Date Request received] between '"+a+"' and '"+b+"'";
        out.print(sql);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
       int count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      conn.commit();
           stmt.close();
           conn.close();
      %>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <%
// The column count starts from 1
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
  String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
  // Do stuff with name%>
  <td nowrap> <%
  out.print(name);%></td>
       <%
}%>
  </tr>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
%>
 <tr>
  <%



 for (int i=1; i<count; i++) {%>

        <td>
            <%=rs.getString(i)%> <%}%>

     <% 
}
      }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.print(e);
            }
      %>
          </td>
 </tr>
</table> 
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i'm trying to run this program i'm getting the below error. actually, the values are not getting passed.

```
 null null select * from [Sheet1$] where [Date Request received] between 'null' and 'null'java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. %>
```

please let me know how do i resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on the form JSP, you are not sending the date1/date2 parameters in your AJAX request, which is why request.getParameter(...) are null. To fix, it, change your `xmlHttp.send()` to:

```
xmlHttp.send("date1=" + document.getElementById('date1').value + "&date2=" + document.getElementById('date2').value);
```

Second, on the connection JSP, you must sanitize your input. Your current code doesn't check if the required parameters are set, and it also allows for an SQL injection attack, because you are inserting request parameters directly into your SQL query. Try something like this:

```
String a=request.getParameter("date1");
String b=request.getParameter("date2");

if (a == null || b == null) {
    // bail out here
    out.print('data1 and date2 are required');
} else {
    // use a prepared statement where we can safely insert the parameters
    sql="select * from [Sheet1$] where [Date Request received] between ? and ?";
    stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, a);
    stmt.setString(2, b);
    rs=stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

Comment: thanks @Jonathan this worked, but can you please tell me how do i form that url plz. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, the string that's passed to send() is a standard "query string". It's key=value pairs joined by &'s, ex. key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3. The query string will be understood by Java so you can get your values with request.getParameter([param name]).